# git-push command failed (401 Unauthorized) when using maven-release-plugin on Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin, jgit

We have configured a Jenkins job that should release our Maven project with the *maven-release-plugin*.

Checking out and building is working without problems but then the following error occurs:

```
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] error: The requested URL returned error: 
  401 Unauthorized while accessing 
     http://server.com:8374/gitblit/r/my-parent-project/info/refs
```

We are using *jgit* to handle the Git commands.

What could be the problem when checking out works but pushing fails?

Comment: Are you sure that the server is authenticating?

Comment: @Makoto What do you mean? I'm sure that the Git repository is checked out correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that the server can authenticate to the Git repository via HTTP?  Wouldn't it have to enter a password of some kind?  (It's not using SSL at that point.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's working now with the following parameters:

```
-Dusername=myUserName -Dpassword=myPassword -DproviderImplementation=jgit
```